# A program that outputs itself in reverse order

Tags: code-golf

Well the title says it all.

- Standard loopholes apply
- Nothing to read from stdin, and output goes to stdout
- 1-byte-long programs are... nonsense. They don't qualify
- A program with a single byte repeated is also a nonsense (like `aaa`)
- **Please mark it out if your program is a palindrome**

Sample:

> A program with source code
>
> ```
> abcde
> ```
>
> should output
>
> ```
> edcba
> ```

Because this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest program wins!

Comment: Is reading the contents of the file allowed, or is that off limits for this challenge?

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 3 bytes

```
1
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/9@Qy@D/fwA)

Pretty sure this has been submitted before, but here's one in RProgN 2.

It outputs

```
0
1
```